# GiNaC order of the output

Tags: c++, ginac

I am building an application written in C++, that heavily involves algebra. I decided to use GiNaC for Computer Algebra System (CAS) It is working perfectly; however there is a little problem. The order of the elements are not how I want them to be in output. Let me give an example. This is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ginac/ginac.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace GiNaC;
    symbol x("x");
    ex poly((x^2)+3*x+5);

    std::cout << poly;
}
```

Output of this program is:

```
5+x^2+3*x
```

Well, I detected that this is not constant, the output ALSO can be:

```
5+3*x+x^2
```

Although, both are mathematically correct the form I want (or maybe I need :-) is neither of them. I want the polynomial to start with the biggest degree, i.e my output should be:

```
x^2+3*x+5
```

This problem is even worse when we add signed numbers, paranthesis or more complex algebraic expression (it sometimes even write (-3+a)x which looks very ugly :-) `std::cout<<GiNaC::latex`
does not fix the problem. And in my point of view, the most annoying part is the erratic behaviour of the output.

Is something like that possible in GiNaC. I also don't want to have a really messy code (because C++0x `<regex>` library can do this easily, but I would rather not involve regular expression, my code is complex enough)
I am using GCC 4.7.2 under Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are referring to is documented [here](http://www.ginac.de/tutorial/Polynomial-arithmetic.html#Polynomial-arithmetic), and it doesn't seem to be any builtin functionality for handling this case.

According to [this](http://www.ginac.de/pipermail/ginac-list/2010-April/001598.html) you need to implement this yourself. Below is a short example code of how this can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ginac/ginac.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace GiNaC;
    symbol x("x");
    ex poly(-3*x-5+power(x,2));

    std::vector<ex> terms(poly.begin(), poly.end());
    std::sort(std::begin(terms), std::end(terms), 
        [x](const ex& lhs, const ex& rhs) { return lhs.degree(x)>rhs.degree(x); });

    bool first{ true };
    for(auto term : terms) {
        if( first ) first = false;
        else if( term.coeff(term)>0) std::cout << '+' ;

        std::cout << term;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```